# SSH reverse tunnel into Docker container

Tags: iptables, docker

I need to xdebug something that fails on the server in a docker container and from my laptop I have ran `ssh -R 9000:localhost:9000 server` and verified the tunnel by `telnet localhost 9000`. So far so good, I got a connection.

Now, on the server I did

```
iptables -t nat -I PREROUTING -p tcp -d 172.17.42.1 --dport 9000 -j DNAT --to 127.0.0.1:9000
```

Finally I have committed the problematic docker instance and ran

```
docker run  --net=host -t  -i snapshot /bin/bash
```

Inside the container `telnet 172.17.42.1 9000` refuses connection.

Comment: i'm rather clueless about docker and rather clueless about iptables on that level, so excuse me if this question makes no sense, but maybe since you ran the iptables command outside the container, it isn't recognized inside, what if you run the iptables command inside the container?

Comment: and can you do any troubleshooting to isolate where the problem is. You have 3 rather involved commands there.  The ssh -R, the iptables with PREROUTING and DNAT, and docker. No doubt keep docker. What if you try nc -l -p 1234 (or whatever the nc syntax for get it to listen on a port is), and skip iptables and do docker and within the container do telnet 127.0.0.1:1234 and see if that works. If it fails, then you have a simpler demonstration of the problem - that helps. If it works, then try to build it up till it fails and that will give a better idea of the cause.

Comment: The ssh -R part works, both telnet and lsof shows that.

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/a/789275/8023 is an answer too.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I ran into this same issue, except I had two containers wired together with --link, so --net=host wont work for that situtaiton.

When doing an ssh port forward to the remote host using `ssh -R 9000:localhost:9000 server`, an `lsof -P -i -n` may show that the port is bound to the servers *loopback* device, which looks like this:

`sshd     39172 ubuntu    9u  IPv4 2941407      0t0  TCP ::1:9000 (LISTEN)`

That loopback interface is not available to the network inside of the docker container.  I remedied this by adding `GatewayPorts yes` to the sshd_config file on the server and restarting sshd.

The forwarded port 9000 is then bound to the normal interface and available from inside the docker container. (and from any other host for that matter).

Answer (score 0):

@barlop 's comment has proven very helpful. I have deleted the iptables rule then I tried to run `nc -l -p 1234` and then `nc -l 127.0.0.1 -p 1234` and then in the container I tried `telnet localhost 1234` and it worked. So I tried `telnet localhost 9000` and it also worked! I think it didn't before but it seems it does now. So: no need for any iptables rules, it just works with `--net=host`. However, lsof -i :9000 still doesn't display anything and it's possible I only tested with that before.

Edit: `netstat -anl |grep :9000` in the container shows the open port as LISTEN. lsof does not. Weird.

Comment: i'm a bit familiar with netstat which I understand covers part of the functionality of lsof. if you do `netstat -apn (or whatever the switches are) | grep :9000`(I don't have netstat output in front of me but I guess that'd be the right grep), are you saying that doesn't show port 9000 open but you can connect to port 9000? Is the server/listening port inside the container? outside the container? or both? And are you running lsof or netstat inside the container? or outside the container? or both? and are you trying to telnet from inside or from outside? btw nc can do telnet `nc server port`.

Comment: `nc -l -p` was run outside of the container to simulate / rule out SSH as the culprit. `telnet` was ran inside the container to check for a connection for real.